# Wordpress Twenty Ten each post published 6 times at same time. Is there a php solution in post.php?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

After moving a friend's Wordpress twenty ten website to a new host with same domain name and adding https, when Admin adds new posts they  always get the id = 1 and always six versions are generated,  saved and published.  Can anyone enighten me on why this happens?

I have deleted all duplicate entries from wp_posts, regenerated the database using the "Optimize Database after Deleting Revisions" plug-in and checked for solutions extensively on the web. Do I need to reinstall WordPress.

Client insists on twenty sixteen.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried tio debug the code that generates the post

Comment: Try disabling all plugins and reactivating them one by one, checking if the problem still occurs. Alternatively reinstall the WordPress core, by deleting all WordPress files except the `wp-content/` folder and the wp-config.php.

Comment: Desctivated Plugins but no joy. Will try to reinstall the WP Core. If I remove all the php files, will they regenerate automatically or must I do a reinstall? Thanks, Yahya

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that, during the upload, the primary index status of the ID attribute was lost. Now I have restored it, posts are working as expected. Thanks for your suggestions anyway.